# Are there *in vitro* studies that find ivermectin directly effective against the SARS-CoV-2 spike or its other proteins?

Tags: sars-cov-2, antivirals

Among the more obscure [papers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7778723/) proposing ivermectin as a treatment for Covid-19 there are some that suggest it acts directly by binding to the SARS-CoV-2 spike protein (and other proteins of that virus too), based on *in silico* (computational) studies:

> It can be deduced that Ivermectin has efficient binding with: (1) spike S1-RBD, where it binds with Thr 500, Asn 501 and Tyr 505 residues. These sites are critical to the SARS CoV-2 spike protein-mediated recognition from ACE-2 receptors in the host cellular system. Prominent H-bonding with Thr 500 and Asn 501 and water bridges were observed for more than 80% of simulation (Fig. 4a). (2) Spike S2-fusion domain, it binds to two specific regions of S2 fusion domain namely HR-1 sub-domain and fusion peptide domain. Major interactions were observed at the HR-1 domain, where it binds for up to 80% of simulation duration with Ser 968, Asn 969 and Gly 971 with H-bonds and water bridges. The fusion peptide region also exhibits weak affinity for ivermectin at Phe 797 and extremely weak interactions at Pro 792 residues with hydrophobic contact (Figs. ​4b). The S2 fusion domain is necessary to build the fusion bridge between the viral and host membrane, where the fusion peptide is highly non-polar flexible region which facilitates the direct contact with the host membrane components. (3) N-protein, the poly-nucleotide (RNA) interacting cleft of nucleocapsid N-protein characterized by residues Arg 69, Tyr 124, Asn 127 and Glu 137 were found interacting with ivermectin with rich H-bond ratio, see Fig 4c. (4) Main protease, the main protease of the SARS-CoV 2 is another target which exhibits good affinity for ivermectin in inhibition site too at Glu 19, Thr 25, Glu 47, Leu 50 (Fig. ​4d).
>
> [image]

On the other hand, the somewhat more cited [papers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7577703/) on ivermectin don't mention that (putative) direct mechanism of action on SARS-CoV-2 at all and only mention host-directed ([IMPα](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importin_%CE%B1)-directed) effects via as the plausible mechanism. (Effects of this latter kind would not be specific to particular viruses, but result in broad anti-viral action, as I understand the issue.)

**So are there *in vitro* (as opposed to *in silico*) studies that find any direct effect (i.e. affinity/avidity) of ivermectin to SARS-CoV-2 proteins as suggested in that first study?** (Such lab studies are normally conducted with pseudoviral particles with just the protein of interest, at least for the spike protein; I'm not sure how one could test the main protease (aka 3CLpro) in that regard though.)

Comment: Obligatory link to the [general question about Ivermectin's efficacy against Covid-19](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/23029/8418).

Answer (score 2):

> Are there *in vitro* studies that find ivermectin directly effective against the SARS-CoV-2 spike or its other proteins?

There are *in vitro* studies: [The FDA-approved drug ivermectin inhibits the replication of SARS-CoV-2 in vitro](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166354220302011), but the exact mechanism appears to be uncertain:

> Taken together these results demonstrate that ivermectin has antiviral
> action against the SARS-CoV-2 clinical isolate in vitro, with a single
> dose able to control viral replication within 24–48 h in our system.
> **We hypothesise that this is likely through inhibiting IMPα/β1-mediated
> nuclear import of viral proteins (Fig. 1G), as shown for other RNA
> viruses** (Tay et al., 2013; Wagstaff et al., 2012; Yang et al., 2020);
> confirmation of this mechanism in the case of SARS-CoV-2, and
> identification of the specific SARS-CoV-2 and/or host component(s)
> impacted (see (Yang et al., 2020)) is an important focus **future work**
> in this laboratory. Ultimately, development of an effective anti-viral
> for SARS-CoV-2, if given to patients early in infection, could help to
> limit the viral load, prevent severe disease progression and limit
> person-person transmission. Benchmarking testing of ivermectin against
> other potential antivirals for SARS-CoV-2 with alternative mechanisms
> of action (Dong et al., 2020; Elfiky, 2020; Gordon et al., 2020; Li
> and De Clercq, 2020; Wang et al., 2020) would thus be important as
> soon as practicable. This Brief Report raises the possibility that
> ivermectin could be a useful antiviral to limit SARS-CoV-2, in similar
> fashion to those already reported (Dong et al., 2020; Elfiky, 2020;
> Gordon et al., 2020; Li and De Clercq, 2020; Wang et al., 2020); until
> one of these is proven to be beneficial in a clinical setting, all
> should be pursued as rapidly as possible.